# How to retrieve records using parameters?

Tags: sql-server

In my table I have several docNums series.

I want to retrieve conditionally either all series or excluding one series from the set.

I tried the following query which returned error

```
declare @p char(1) = 1

select 
    t0.docNum  
from   
    OINV t0
where  
    t0.DocNum = case
                   when @p  <> '1' then t0.DocNum                             
                   else (select t1.DocNum
                         from oinv t1
                         where SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, t1.docNum), 1, 1) <> '9' 
                           and LEN(convert(varchar, t1.docNum)) < 7)
                end
```

What should be the correct query?

Comment: What was your error?

Comment: You have several issues going on here. First you should define string literals with '1'. Then you are converting to varchar but you don't specify the length. There are defaults for the length and they change based on usage. Be explicit. And this looks a bit over complicated but really hard to tell what is going on. Would help if you posted the error message instead of just saying you got an error.

Comment: When you're just starting learning SQL, it's a good idea to run your query for every statement rather than writing the complete query with tons of mistake.  I can see that it will fail on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you were getting an error message about a subquery returning more than 1 row. That is because your subquery would return all the rows from the table. You would need to correlate that subquery to the outer query to avoid this. But you don't need to use a subquery here at all. This can be simplified to something like this.

```
declare  @p  char(1) = '1'

select o.docNum  
from OINV o
where @p  <> '1'
OR 
(
    SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(10/*whatever size is appropriate*/), o.docNum), 1, 1) <> '9' 
    and 
    LEN(convert(varchar(10/*whatever size is appropriate*/), o.docNum)  ) < 7
)
```